# What is yet needed to leave the beta status?

Tags: discussion, beta

Checking periodically the [Area51 page of the site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering), I am very happy that most stat are at least in "okay" status. Although the question/day stat is still seems to oscillate around the required minimum (5), it seems it doesn't endanger the site's future (btw, there are betas with much smaller q/d and there was an Embedded Systems SE with bigger stat, despite that it was killed in private beta. Or there is the Magento SE with its around 40 q/d still in beta).

Somewhere I've read, that the SE allows a site to leave the beta, if its visit (or q/d) stat starts to get an exponencial grow. There is no objective measurements, the CMs want to see a curve starting an exponencial growing phase. But, unfortunately I can't find this post any more.

The q/d stat of the site clearly doesn't grow, it is in constant, or in a slowly growing linear phase, it is clearly visible. The other stats seem much better.

Anybody knows or thinks more? 5k+ users have access to the site stats, are there positive / negative tendencies?

Comment: [This meta answer](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/a/79/16) has been tracking our Area51 stats.  In general, all of the metrics are trending towards the positive.  As to how long it will take for us to leave beta status?  Probably quite some time still as we need a much larger body of questions to help drive search traffic.  But with generally positive stats, we're not at risk of being shut down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our current criteria for when a site is ready to graduate is explained [in this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites):

> **When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation.**

As you point out yourself, Engineering is still oscillating around 5 questions/day — however, note that our new criteria also point out that that does not mean the site's future is endangered. Our current take on that is that:

> **If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed.**

---

As a side note, [Magento is no longer in Beta](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/its-election-and-graduation-eve) (you'll notice it does not have the "Beta" label any more), as a part of the new [Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) — it's only missing regular reputation levels and a site design.